# How to access common declared types from a function in Drools?

Tags: drools

Here am having multiple Rules in a .drl file. They are updating 6 different JSONArray. These updates are happening in the "then" section of the Drools. Rather than having the similar logic inside the rule, am trying to write a function which will update the 6 JSONArray. How would that be possible ?

```
declare USER1_LIST
     querysetUser1 :JSONArray
end
declare USER2_LIST
     querysetUser2 :JSONArray
end
......
......
......
```

The initialization is happening in a "Set Up" rule with highest Salience -

```
rule "setUp"
salience 25
when
then
USER1_LIST user1_list = new USER1_LIST();
user1_list.setQuerysetUser1(new JSONArray());
insert(user1_list);
....
```

In the rule am using one of the list based on the logic -

```
rule "RULE_XYZ"
salience 5
when
USER1_LIST($querysetUser1 :querysetUser1)
...<Some code>
then
...<Some code>
$querysetUser1.add(...);
```

Here I want to perform the operation "$querysetUser1.add(...);" inside a function. These JSONArray are updated by different rules. So my aim is to move the logic of selecting the JSONArray and updating it in a function, so that only this function would be called from different rules.

Comment: So what's the problem? Declare a function and do so.

Comment: Also it is important what version of Drools you are using.

Comment: No am not able to access that querysetUser2 in the function. What would be the syntax for that ?

Comment: You would write a function that takes an instance of JSONArray and does whatever. Or that takes an instances of USER2_LIST.

Comment: Is there anyway we can do it, without passing the JSONArray to the function ? Am thinking about function like "addToArray(jsonobject);". And in the function based on the logic it will add "jsonobject" to the appropriate array.

Comment: What is a "jsonobject"? You have USER1_LIST (etc) and JSONArray in your code. If USER1_LIST is actually a "jsonobject", then you shouldn't have declared a new type....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declared types can be accessed in declared functions. However, from your example, it sounds like you just need to be able to do work against the JSONArray objects contained within the declared types.

The function would look something like this:

```
function void addToQuerySet(JSONArray querySet, JSONObject object) {// I have guessed the type of 'object'
  querySet.add(object);
}
```

And you would invoke it from the `then` clause:

```
rule "RULE_XYZ"
when
  USER1_LIST($querysetUser1 :querysetUser1)
  // ...<Some code>
  someObject: JSONObject() // the thing to insert
then
  addToQuerySet($querysetUser1, someObject);
end
```

What you cannot do is write a generic method that will take any of your `USER1_LIST`, `USER2_LIST`, etc declared types because they're all unique and unrelated types, even if they all share the same structure.

Note that the fact that your declared types sharing the same structure is indicative of poor design -- it is likely they should all be instances of a single type, with somet other way of identifying which user it belongs to. For example, something like this:

```
declare UserList 
  querySet: JSONArray
  userNum: int
end
```

Where `userNum` would indicate which user this is for. Then you could write a function that takes a `UserList` and a `JSONObject` (or whatever the type is of that thing is you're adding to the query set) like so:

```
function void addToQuerySet(UserList userList, JSONObject object) {
  userList.getQuerySet().add(object);
}
```

And invoke it in a `then` clause like so:

```
rule "RULE XYZ version 2"
when
  $user1List: UserList( userNum == 1, querySet != null)
  // more code
  $someObject: JSONObject() // to insert
then
  addToQuerySet( $user1List, $someObject );
end
```

Please refer to the documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.11.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_function). I have linked to the Drools 7.11.0.Final documentation, specifically the section on functions; the section on declared types is the following section and quite extensive.